# How do I create new routes with ningle after app wrapped in middleware?

Tags: routes, common-lisp, middleware

i'm relatively new to common lisp and ningle/(c)lack, and i'm having trouble adding new routes to my app after adding middleware. if i add middleware, i get a no applicable method error on adding or updating a route.

my middleware looks like so:

```lisp
(defparameter *application-root* (asdf:system-source-directory :my-project))
(defparameter *static-directory* (merge-pathnames #P"static/" *application-root*))

(setf *app*
      (lack:builder
       (:static
        :path (lambda (path)
                (if (ppcre:scan "^(?:/images/|/css/|/js/|/robot\\.txt$|/favicon\\.$)" path)
                    path
                    nil))
        :root *static-directory*)
       :backtrace
       :session
       (lambda (app)
         (lambda (env)
           (funcall app env)))
       *app*))
```

if i try to add a new route to my app after that code loads, i receive a no applicable method error.

a route:

```lisp
(setf (n:route *app* "agents/:id/endpoint" :method :post)
      #'(lambda (params)
          (route-fun params)))
```

the error looks like so:

```lisp
There is no applicable method for the generic function
  #<standard-generic-function (common-lisp:setf ningle/app:route) (1)>
when called with arguments
  (#<function (lambda (params)
                :in
                "/path/to/code/app.lisp") {123456789}>
   #<function (lambda (lack.middleware.static::env)
                :in
                "/path/to/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/lack-20230214-git/src/middleware/static.lisp") {123456789}>
   "agents/:id/endpoint" :method :post).
```

i also receive the error if i try to recompile any existing routes. i don't know how to unwrap my app, so whenever i want to add or edit a route i have to re-start my lisp session entirely. i know the routes themselves are fine, they work otherwise.

EDIT: i just tried it with a very minimal middleware and i still have the same issue:

```lisp
(setf *app*
      (lack:builder
       :backtrace
       :session
       *app*))
```

EDIT: my app binding looks like so:

```lisp
(defvar *app* (make-instance 'n:app))
```

Comment: `lack:builder` depends on the previous binding of `*app*` but your example does not include its previous definition, could you add it ? maybe if you name each layer differently, for example `*base-app*`, `*middleware-app*`, `*app*` you can add route at the appropriate layer?

Comment: that seems to work, thanks. i was assuming i had some error in what i was doing, or that the experts had some trick up their sleeve. i think only two variables are needed: base-app (pre-midware, route on that) and app (mid-ware added to base-app, used by clackup).